# Where can I hunt wild boars for free in Southeast Texas?

Tags: united-states, hunting, boars, texas

It is said that Southeast Texas is overrun by wild boars. However, I have only seen sign of them within national park borders-where hunting is not allowed-and all google search results return paid hunting ranches which I regard as "pig farms". Where can I go hunt wild pigs in southeast Texas without paying?

Comment: Free is unrealistic, you'll probably have to pay for a permit of some kind if you're not on a private ranch.

Comment: In Texas you can shoot boars without a permit, but you do need a hunting license. See http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/huntwild/wild/nuisance/feral_hogs/#hunt

Comment: The parks and wildlife site goes to great lengths not to say explicitly where you can hunt those wild boars. I'm not sure if that means that feral boars are such a nuisance that you can hunt them anywhere it's not specified otherwise, or if it's somehow confidential. Either way, you should give that department a call and find out, and then post the answer here as long as they don't tell you not to.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: there's a lot of public land, most likely state owned (not federal), that's available for hunting.

[image: Counties offering public hunting by annual permit]
<sub>(source: [state.tx.us](http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/huntwild/hunt/public/lands/images/Texas_Public_Hunting_Map.jpeg))</sub>  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwJvI.jpg)

There might be limitations for nonresidents and/or based on what you plan to hunt with (e.g. firearm, black powder, bow) but this looks like a great starting point for information:

**Public Hunting and Access to TPWD Lands**

"Texas Parks and Wildlife Department (TPWD) offers a variety of hunting opportunities through two public hunting systems."[2]

Here's the Texas page for licensing: 
http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/business/licenses/online_sales/

Here's a breakout of licenses with associated fees for both residents and non-residents:
http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/business/licenses/public/recreational/index.phtml

If you can add a bit more information about what you're looking for I can try to be a bit more specific.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwJvI.jpg) http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/huntwild/hunt/public/lands/table_contents/7houston.phtml#offerings

[2] http://www.tpwd.state.tx.us/huntwild/hunt/public/

Side note, as for search terms try, "texas game and wildlife hunting license" and "texas public hunting land".  I suspect you'll get fewer ranch ads if you're specifically including the word "public" in your query.

Comment: There is also a lot of National Forest land in TX. A surprise to some because when TX joined the Union  there was very little land transferred to the US Government. But, as i understand, during the 30's much E TX forest land was taken  for non-payment of federal taxes.  There is a chunk of this land behind my house, complete with hogs , come and get them.  Look up Sam Houston National  Forest rules. I know it is an open season.